# List packages - software with their size and last use

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, uninstall

I would like to know if there is any way on ubuntu to get a list of softwares/packages installed on the machine with their size and last use.

This is something which I have on windows and it is really useful because it helps me understanding which software I installed and which of them I am not using anymore. In this way I could delete them in order to make some space on my computer.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and the command

```
dpkg -l
```

Just gives me a list of software but **NOT their size/use**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n` will give you a list of packages sorted by size. If you're new to Linux, deleting stuff is not really advisable unless you want to learn by breaking your system!